# how to retrieve the request body parameters in magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, database, magento-2.0

Client request url with some POST data. How can I retrieve that variable in magento?

I have to retrieve that in JSON format variable and do the operation using those variables.

Comment: i am using OAUTH authentication for my API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We insert our JSON data in request body in this form:

```
{
    "firstname":"vijay",
    "secondname":"bokka",
    "email":"vijayiiitn@gmail.com"
}
```

As part of API implementation one method will be invoked when API URL is trigged.

To that method interface write:

```
apiinvokedmethod($firstname, $secondname, $email)
{

}
```

You can access value of `$firstname` automatically in the class where you implemented this interface class.

**NOTE**: The value of **key** in json and name of the method **parameter** should be equal.